# How to expose aks service cluster port to the internet?

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I am a beginner with Kubernetes and azure. I know that a service in my cluster exposés port like 32111.but that is not accessible from the internet. What should I do to forward that service port to the internet?

When I run kubectl get services myservcie I get info that externalip is none

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Service of type `LoadBalancer`.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/

Kubernetes will "ask" Azure to create a public Load Balancer with a specific port.

Answer (score -2):

There is no one line answer, because everything has to be set right. Below is an article that I believe explains everything a bit clearly, go through it an see what you miss.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/